# How to create pseudo-color figures with IDL Graphics

Tags: idl-programming-language

I want to plot a 2-D matrix as a pseudo-color figure in IDL, just like the function `pcolor` in matlab. I know the function `image` can do that, but I hope it can generate IDL Graphics like the `plot`, `scatterplot`, etc, in order to use the methods and keywords of Graphics. My current procedure(see below) loops the `polygon` to plot every rectangular pixel, which takes too long. Is there a brief way to make that?

```
  gr = plot([x_vertex[0]],[y_vertex[0]],_EXTRA=ex)
  for i = 0,n_elements(x)-2 do begin
    for j = 0,n_elements(y)-2 do begin
      if ~finite(z[i,j]) then continue

      pl = polygon([x_vertex[i],x_vertex[i+1],x_vertex[i+1],x_vertex[i]],$
        [y_vertex[j],y_vertex[j],y_vertex[j+1],y_vertex[j+1]],$
        fill_color=color_list[i,j],/data,rgb_table=rgb_table,linestyle=6)
      ; color_list is calculated from z
    endfor
  endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want black lines between the pixels when you are displaying a small image to indicate each pixel? No need to draw a separate polygon for each pixel, just draw one horizontal one for each row and one vertical one for each column.

If you don't need the dividing lines, just a single call to `image` should do it:

```
IDL> im = image(my_image, rgb_table=my_rgb_table)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just find I misunderstood the usage of `image`. It can generate Graphic Object.